# Ember data and promises in model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm currently trying to load an array of promises to the model, but when I start looping through results in the template, I can't access any relationships.
Even though if I just return a single promise, I can access the relationships within the template.

I'm I missing something on how to handle the return values from the promises to be handle as if it was single?

Using
- Ember & Ember-Data 1.13.8

Model - grouped item

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  group:          DS.belongsTo('group', { async :  false }),
});
```

Model - group

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    code:          DS.attr('string'),
    name:          DS.attr('string'),
});
```

Single model example

```
model : function(){
   return this.store.query('groupedItem', { group_code: 'HOME', position : 1 });
}
```

In template I can access model relationships like this

```
{{#each model as |section|}}
  <p>{{section.id}}</p>
  <p>{{section.group.id}}
{{/each}}
```

------ Model as array promise --------

```
model : function(){
   return Ember.RSVP.Promise.all(Ember.A([
      this.store.query('groupedItem', { group_code: 'HOME', position : 1 }),
      this.store.query('groupedItem', { group_code: 'HOME', position : 2 }),
    ]))
}
```

In template, accessing relationships fails

```
{{#each model as |section|}}
  {{#each section.content as |item|}}
     <p>{{item.id}}</p>
     <p>{{item.group.id}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Here is a json response example

https://gist.github.com/abFx/873465813cf30746acf9

In order to follow json rules to send a proper relationship, I created a custom serializer that just transforms de name instead of group_id to group with and id for relationship

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  isNewSerializerAPI: true,
  normalizeResponse: function(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType){
    payload['grouped_items'].forEach(function(value, index){
      value['group'] = value['group_id'];
    });
    return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType);
  }
});
```

Comment: What is your version of ember ?

Comment: What is your example response for findQuery?

Comment: @dynamic_cast 1.13.8

Comment: @DanielKmak here is an example - https://gist.github.com/abFx/873465813cf30746acf9